# registering kernels in ipython/jupyter notebook - kernel.json

Tags: python, ipython, ijulia-notebook

With the latest version of `IPython`, kernels can be registered by placing a `kernel.json` file in `~/.ipython/kernels/<kernel-name>/`.

I am currently trying to add a `julia` and a `R` kernel and I am wondering who is responsible for creating and maintaining those `kernel.json` files.

Currently, I googled and created following `kernel.json` for julia by hand:

```
{
 "display_name": "Julia",
 "language": "julia",
 "argv": [
    "julia",
    "-i",
    "-F",
    "/User/<user>/.julia/v0.3/IJulia/src/kernel.jl",
    "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "codemirror_mode":"julia"
}
```

While this works, due the hardcoded path to `kernel.jl` I will have to adapt `kernel.json` for every major `julia` upgrade.

Do I have to take care of creating and maintaining these files? Or are they part of the kernel implementations or other third party packages?

Answer (score 1):

Usually people create symbolic links to avoid depending on specific versions.

```
ln -s ~/.julia/v0.3 ~/.julia/latest
```

then you could use `latest` instead of `v0.3` in kernel.json.

When you change versions you will only have to change the symbolic link.

Comment: Yes, that is an option. But IMO changing a symbolic link or editing a path in a config file does not make much of a difference.

Comment: but with a symbolic link when you upgrade you *only has to change the link*  instead of trying to change every program that has ever referenced it.

Comment: I agree that recreating a symlink is an improvement over revising multiple config files. But here I have just one config file, so in this specific case it may be a little cleaner, but does not really solve this issue.