# How to launch Jupyter Notebook with python command line flags?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, command-line-arguments

I want to disable hash randomization for a particular Jupyter notebook. For a regular script, I do this via the `python -R` flag. How can I achieve the same thing when running `jupter-notebook`?

Of course I can achieve this particular goal via setting the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environmental variable but I would like to do it via the flag since it is more flexible.

Comment: Command lines in `jupyter -notebook` apply to the Python session that runs the server, not the kernel that processes the notebook code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by either editing the `kernel.json` file or registering new kernel with changed `kernel.json` file.

`kernel.json` contains `argv` attribute that essentially a command to run python.

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

### Editing existing `kernel.json` file

You can find your `kernel.json` by running:

```
→ jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
  python3           /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/jupyter/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

You can edit it to your liking.

### Insalling custom kernel

You can use the command from previous solution to find the existing `kernel.json`

then install the new kernel:

```
jupyter kernelspec install  /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/jupyter/share/jupyter/kernels/python3 --name=python3_custom --user
```

Find your `python3_custom` location with

`jupyter kernelspec list`

and edit the `kernel.json` there

[Jupyterlab kernel docs](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html)

[registering kernels in ipython/jupyter notebook - kernel.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28442624/9820085)